# find the instance makes two queries different

Tags: database, database-schema

Given any schema of a database and any two queries regarding this database, try to find the smallest instance that causes the two queries having different result sets.

1. I can only come up with an idea of how to find the difference between two queries, i.e. treat the result of each query as a subtable and compare the two tables to see if they are the same. Yet I am not sure whether this will work or not
2. have no clue about how to find the smallest instance, can anyone give me some hint or inspiration?
   should I start to construct the instance making use of the info from the two queries or from the schema of the database or I am heading the wrong direction?
   Thanks a lot!

update1: database instance is a scenario in which each table of the database has some specific values for its attributes.

for instance,

schema:

```
table A:  attr1 attr2...             table B: attr1  attr2  attr3 ...
```

I have to find in what scenario of the database that two arbitrary queries will return different results?

Comment: What do you mean with "instance"?

Comment: Potential dup of [SQL to find the difference between two rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588229/sql-to-find-the-difference-between-two-rows)

Comment: You really need to give some examples of what you are talking about.  Explaining differences between queries that are not provided in the question is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: i am not asking for explaining the difference of two queries. The two queries are arbitrary that's why i can not offer. besides, the schema of the database is also arbitrary.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: database instance is a scenario in which each table of the database has some specific values for its attributes.

Comment: @AmesISU: Your question isn't even remotely clear. What attributes are you talking about? What are you talking about at all?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server, I believe that you want to see the difference of two results from two queires.

Use `EXCEPT` like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table2
```